# iOS app push feature suddenly went broken. Any hint?

Tags: ios, openssl, push, apple-push-notifications

I've just updated my iOS dev program, and renewed the cert / prov required for my little app. However, the push feature suddenly went broken. I've tried everything I can but still no luck.

1. I've checked the provision profile and all certificates, they are correctly set, at least as I know.
2. I've generated the pem file, and tested it with openssl command, it returns ok 0, so the pem should be ok too. The input used to test is:
   openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apns-pro.pem -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
3. Devices has been registered correctly on my server with push options and device UIDs etc.
4. My iPhone 4 can recieve push notifications from other apps, so it's not a problem of the device.
5. The server is written in PHP. Using fwrite to put the payload through ssl link was successful, and bytes were written to the push server with no problem.

The strange part of this is, the push server didn't give me any error, and the feedback tracking got me 'success' results, so the server -> APNS connection should be fine. My device is good with push notifications too, since it recieves notifications from other apps. I really don't know where or what went wrong. I'm totally desperate on this.

Comment: did you verify that you are using appropriate certificates for dev and production environment? Also check if the device token has got updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by regenerating all provision files and the certificate again. It seems like my cert generated was not matching the new provisioning profile.